# C++: What is the correct cast for offseting to std::vector iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, offset, static-cast

I have a function that takes a `std::vector` of doubles, and copies them to another vector, but at a particular offset (assume there is sufficient space):

```
void copy_stuff(const std::vector<double> & data,
                std::vector<double> & dest,
                size_t dest_offset) {
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), dest.begin() + dest_offset);
}
```

This results in a C++11 clang compiler `-Weverything` warning centered on the `+ dest_offset` part:

> Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'difference_type' (aka 'long').

I'm not sure how I should cast the expression `dest.begin() + dest_offset` in order to eliminate this warning. Casting the result to a `double *` does not compile:

```
    std::copy(data, data + data_size, static_cast<double *>(dest.begin() + dest_offset));
```

> Cannot cast from type 'std::__1::__wrap_iter' to pointer type 'double *'.

I had considered using vector indexing and then taking the address:

```
    std::copy(data, data + data_size, &dest[dest_offset]);
```

This seems to eliminate the warning in this case, but doesn't compile if I try to use the same pattern with the source vector, i.e. with an offset involved with the first or second parameter of `std::copy`. For example:

```
static void copy_stuff_differently(const std::vector<double> & data,
                                   std::vector<double> & dest,
                                   size_t offset) {
    std::copy(data.begin() + offset, data.end(), dest.begin());
}
```

Gives the same original warning of implicit conversion on the `+ offset`. Attempting to use the address-of-index might suggest:

```
    std::copy(&data[offset], data.end(), dest.begin());
```

Or a different but similar case:

```
    std::copy(data.begin(), &data[offset], dest.begin());
```

However both cause a similar error:

```
test.cpp:8:3: error: no matching function for call to 'copy'
  std::copy(&data[offset], data.end(), dest.begin());
  ^~~~~~~~~
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1286:48: note:
      candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Ip' ('const double *' vs.
      'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const double *>')
    template <class _Ip, class _Op> friend _Op copy(_Ip, _Ip, _Op);
                                               ^
```

I'm looking for a consistent and warning-free way to handle such offsets. What is the right way to handle offsets into a vector and avoid such errors and warnings?

Comment: clang developers very explicitly say that you should ***NOT*** use -Weverything.

Comment: does `std::next(std::begin(), dest_offset)` change anything?

Answer (score 7):

> I'm not sure how I should cast the expression `dest.begin() + dest_offset` in order to eliminate this warning.

The warning is just telling you that `dest_offset` is expected to be of the type `std::vector::difference_type`, but it's `size_t`.

You can do the conversion explicitly to eliminate the warning (note that if the source value can't be represented in `difference_type` the result is implementation-defined). e.g.

```
dest.begin() + static_cast<std::vector<double>::difference_type>(dest_offset)
```

Or declare the parameter `dest_offset` with the type `difference_type` from the beginning.

Note that [std::vector::difference_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types) is a signed integer type (usually [std::ptrdiff_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t)), which is different from [size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t); which is an unsigned integer type.

Comment: I'd say the parameter should be of type `std::vector<double>::difference_type` and not `size_t` to begin with.

Comment: Does `std::next(dest.begin(), dest_offset)` avoid the warning? I don't have clang to test it on right now.

Comment: @Blastfurnace `std::next` expects a `difference_type` too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I had come across `difference_type` I just hadn't realised it can be used like that. I think @n.m. is probably right - `dest_offset` should be a difference_type in the first place.

Comment: *which is different from size_t* maybe mention that for safe/secure/whatever you name it code one would check if dest_offset <= std::numeric_limits<std::vector<double>::difference_type>, e.g. by using boost::numeric_cast or similar

Comment: @n.m. I think, rather not the `difference_type`, but `ptrdiff_t`. Using the `difference_type` specifically ties one to the vector container, whereas the "offset functional" is not specific to vectors. So a user could replace the container at some point, and still be able to index into it.

Comment: Although now that I wire up that type into my code: I'm getting errors *(warnings without -Werror)* about comparing offset to size(), and size is `size_t`. Given it's the first time I ever met a problem with "difference_type", and size_t is used everywhere else, I guess it's better to not use any of `difference_type` or `ptrdiff_t`. Just work around it with a cast.

Comment: Note that a `size_t` that is larger than `intptrdiff_t` is UB. You can't create arrays that are larger than a pointer difference can represent. Any offset like that would be out-of-bounds. `size_t` should really just be <= 63bit, whatever the max object size is limited to on the arch.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *some* `difference_type` to avoid this warning all together:

```
#include<vector>

using difference_type = std::vector<double>::difference_type;
    
void copy_stuff(const std::vector<double> & data,
                std::vector<double> & dest,
//                size_t dest_offset)
                difference_type dest_offset)
{
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), dest.begin() + dest_offset);
}
```

---

It is widely accepted nowadays [citation needed] that reporting/using sizes and some offsets as unsigned integer types was a mistake in the design of the Standard Library.
So in my opinion the best is to not follow that convention and cast unsigned types from the standard library as soon as possible instead of adapting your function to use unsigned types.

For example `copy_stuff(a.begin(), a.end(), static_cast<difference_type>(other.size()) )`.

---

**UPDATE 2022:** The Ranges library in C++20 (`std::ranges`) has a function called `std::ranges::ssize` that will give the size of the contained as a signed integer type.
This way it will be easier to extract sizes an have a consistent use of signed type for any subsequent arithmetic operation.

For example `copy_stuff(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ranges::ssize(other) )`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider using this - initial experiments show that it does indeed make a lot of the warnings disappear.

Comment: shouldn't you then check that `dest_offset>=0`?

Comment: @Walter Unfortunately, it is a mistake to think that because the type is unsigned it warranties that the positive value makes sense. If you feed a negative number to function it will convert it to a large positive number, which doesn't make sense either. The only thing you do by using a unsigned type is to hide the error. I say "unfortunately" because it makes mathermatical sense but in practice it doesn't work because "unsigned types" are really a bad name for "modulo types". You can add that check but it has a cost, it is better to make sure that the program logic make sense.