# Narrowing conversion size_t to long

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

How should I write this to appease clang-tidy?

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    size_t index = 2;
    auto it = v.begin() + index;
    auto rollover = (index + 1) % v.size();
}
```

clang-tidy complains

> Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
> to signed type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iteratorstd::basic_string<char
> *, std::vectorstd::basic_string<char>>::difference_type' (aka 'long') is implementation-defined

If I use `long` for `index`, the mod operation narrows `v.size()` if I use the more
sensible `size_t` for `index` the `v.begin() + index` narrows `index`. (Why is the iterators operator+ only defined for a signed type anyways? g++11.2.0)

Is there a way to get around this without using `static_cast<long>` all over the place?

[C++ Insights demo](https://%20https://cppinsights.io/s/c45b9eab)

Comment: its not the iterator that is signed but the argument to its `operator+`

Comment: Related: [C++: What is the correct cast for offseting to std::vector iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480794/c-what-is-the-correct-cast-for-offseting-to-stdvector-iterator)

Comment: Maybe choose one or the other when it comes to indices or iterators. This example is a bit contrived, and it would be better to see a real example. As for the iterator, see [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) or similar documentation. Operations on such iterators are signed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Corrected, thanks.

Comment: In any case, just using `+1ULL` could already work. Or `+1UL`.

Comment: @paddy The non-contrived code sits at 760 lines of code. I'm pretty sure no-one here is interested in that =)

Comment: I meant that seeing some kind of real-world example where you need to mix these types in such a way as to need loads of casts might help understand your goals.

Comment: @paddy I'm iterating over a file-list. There are next(), previous() that uses the second construct. A current() that uses the first. And plenty of similar uses.

Comment: C-style casts are nice and short (just sayin')

Comment: @PaulSanders I ended up doing just that.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Sensible move.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::vector<int>::difference_type`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, that is actually what I'm using now. Casting with an alias for that difference type.